# Chaos Theory Question

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm wondering if there is a general formula or approach for chaos theory? Or, if not, are there any books of papers that I can reference for learning about Chaos Theory?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, then the first paper that introduced the word "chaos" was here: http://faculty.washington.edu/joelzy/LiYorke_period3.pdf, entitled "Period Three Implies Chaos."

However, the general notion went back a bit earlier, I believe with regard to weather and natural phenomena. Regardless, the paper linked above might be a nice starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I've been reading a book on the history of math, and a part about Henri Poincare came along, with his analysis of three body movement, and after a while this study was stated as wrong to Henri. But it actually showed how incomprehensible movement becomes based on initial points and further motion. Just seemed crazy to me, so I would like to look into what is referred to as Chaos Theory that Henri Poincare helped develop. Cheers for sharing though!

Answer (score 0):

You may enjoy these books:

- [Celestial Encounters:The Origins of Chaos and Stability](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5913.html) by Diacu and Holmes
- [Does God Play Dice? The New Mathematics of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_God_Play_Dice%3F_The_New_Mathematics_of_Chaos) by Ian Stewart