# Book on Chaos Theory

Tags: book-recommendation, chaos-theory

Please suggest some good chaos theory as general read, which can be enjoyed while on beach has patterns.
I am a electrical Eng Post Graduate in communication theory and signal processing so can understand complex math.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1336551/589.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gleick's [Chaos: Making a New Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0143113453) is a beautiful book that can be read without pencil and paper.

Answer (score 7):

Divulgative:

[Does God Play Dice? The New Mathematics of Chaos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631232516) by Ian Stewart.

A bit more advanced:

[Explaining Chaos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521477476) by Peter Smith.

College level:

[Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783540609346) by Ferdinand Verhulst.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my suggestions:

- Stephen Strogatz **Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos**
- Online SOOC **chaosbook.org**
- Edward Ott **Chaos in Dynamical Systems**

If you know nothing about nonlinear dynamics, then Strogatz is the best place to start. If you want to jump straight into chaos, then go with Edward Ott's book. I recently discovered the online SOOC--just started, but it seems very promising!

Comment: I really enjoyed chaosbook.org. +1

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations are:

> Ivar Ekeland: *The broken dice, and other mathematical tales of chance*
>
> Vladimir Arnold: *Catastrophe Theory*.